# How to order in pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This question similiar from my previous question, but i have no idea to find the solution, because im not using union.

i have this query

```
CREATE TABLE #SampleData
(
    Name varchar(10),
    Location varchar(20),
    Item varchar(10),
    Date varchar(8)
)
INSERT INTO #SampleData
VALUES
('Ron', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170610'),
('Ron', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170611'),
('Ron', 'Loc B', 'Pen', '20170610'),
('Ron', 'Loc B', 'Laptop', '20170611'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170611'),
('Tom', 'Loc B', 'Pencil', '20170610'),
('Tom', 'Loc B', 'Pen', '20170610'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170610'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Laptop', '20170610'),
('Tom', 'Loc A', 'Pencil', '20170610')

    DECLARE @Pivot_Columns  AS VARCHAR(MAX),
            @select_Columns VARCHAR(max)

    SELECT @Pivot_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(Item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
    SELECT @select_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',Sum(' + Quotename(Item) + ') as '+Quotename(Item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

    DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT case when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 0 then ''Total''+ '' '' + name 
    when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 1 then ''Total'' 
    else name end Name, 
    case when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 0 then CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(Distinct location ))
    when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 1 then CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(Distinct location ))
    else Location end Location,
    '+ @select_Columns + '
    FROM
    (
        SELECT name, location, item
        FROM #SampleData

    ) as PivotData
    PIVOT
    (
        count(item)
        for item  IN ('
               + @Pivot_Columns + ')
    ) AS PivotResult
    group by name,location with rollup 
    '

    EXEC(@SQL)
```

and the result like this:

[image]

how to order my query looks like this? if theres no count of my location my query work fine

[image]

i need the solution to fix this problem, thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Is this type of output acceptable ?

```
Name             Location             Laptop      Pen         Pencil
---------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Ron              Loc A                0           0           2
Ron              Loc B                1           1           0
Ron Total        2                    1           1           2
Tom              Loc B                0           1           1
Tom              Loc A                1           0           3
Tom Total        2                    1           1           4
Total            2                    2           2           6
```

The query I have used :

```
DECLARE @Pivot_Columns  AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @select_Columns VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @Pivot_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + Quotename(Item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
SELECT @select_Columns = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',Sum(' + Quotename(Item) + ') as '+Quotename(Item) FROM #SampleData FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT case when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 0 then name + '' ''+ ''Total''
when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 1 then ''Total'' 
else name end Name, 
case when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 0 then CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(Distinct location ))
when grouping(location) = 1 and grouping(name) = 1 then CONVERT(varchar(10), COUNT(Distinct location ))
else Location end Location,
'+ @select_Columns + '
FROM
(
    SELECT name, location, item
    FROM #SampleData

) as PivotData
PIVOT
(
    count(item)
    for item  IN ('
           + @Pivot_Columns + ')
) AS PivotResult
group by name,location with rollup 
ORDER BY GROUPING (name), name'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: I don't think so, because i have many Total by date below Total in bottom of my table.